# Regex: Find where letters end and numbers start

Tags: php, regex

I have strings like `MA14` or `MD22b` and I have to find the index between `MA`and `14`.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: What did you come up with yourself? Do you know that an index IS actually a char? There's no in between...

Comment: I found `(?<=\d)(.*)(?=[A-Z])` but it doesn't work

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eE0iC6/1)

ind demo the `()` for group capturing is added, to display indices on which it match.

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex:

```
string s = "ABC142";    
var r= new Regex("^([A-Za-z]*)(\\d*)$");
var m = r.Match(s);
m.Groups[1].Index.Dump();  # index of the match
m.Groups[1].ToString().Dump();
m.Groups[2].Index.Dump(); # index of the match
m.Groups[2].ToString().Dump();
```

will print

```
0
ABC
3
142
```

(`Dump` is from LINQPAd, you can use `Console.WriteLine` etc).

Comment: OP said it's php.  But this is a nice .NET solution.